# How to clear the buffer of a streamstring?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, buffer

I have a streamstring in two loops and it is burning my RAM. So how to clear properly the buffer of a steamstring? It is like that to simplify :

```
stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);

for()
{
    for()
    {
        val = 2;
        ss << 2;
        mystring = ss.str();
        // my stuff
    }
    // Clear the buffer here
}
```

It wrote 2 then 22 then 222... I tried .clear() or .flush() but it is not that. So how I do this?

Comment: I would put the stringstream into the loop.

Comment: If I put std::stringstream ss; in a loop it will creat many ss in the RAM and will burn it no? Or it will delete ss at the end of his loop because it is created in a loop? (It feel a noob question here :) but I am! )

Comment: it is created and destroyed as the program loops. BTW, what do you mean with "burn the RAM"?

Comment: My app grow in 30s at 2Go and crash. "it is created and destroyed as the program loops" I didn't know that, I thought it create many ss and they would destroy at the end of the function/app/object. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use a new `stringstream` each time, e.g.:

```
for (...) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (...) {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

This is the way `stringstream` was designed to be used.  (Also: do you
really want a `stringstream`, or just an `ostringstream`?)

Comment: I use it here to change a float in a string and put this string in a big other string. What is the best to do that? And if I put std::stringstream ss; in a loop it will creat many ss in the RAM no?

Comment: `std::ostringstream ss; ss << theDouble; theString += ss.str();`  And if the `stringstream` is in the loop, there will still only be one in memory at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Set `ss.str("");` when you want to clear out the excess characters (Edit: thank you).

Use `.clear()` if your stream has set any error flags in the process of the prior conversion.

Comment: It is usually not enough. You should also use `seekp(0)` and `seekg(0)`, too.

Comment: @Naszta I was able to do it without the `seekp/seekg` portion after setting the string and then clearing the stream.

Comment: @jonsca: in this case it depends on the implementation. I had many issue on it before. (I develop multi platform, I don't remember which implementation had/has this issue.)

Comment: For future reference, this is covered in Scott Meyers books on C++ (which I recommend).

Comment: @csl: [Effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876/ref=dp_ob_title_bk), [More effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/More-Effective-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/020163371X) and [Effective STL](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Specific-Standard-Template/dp/0201749629)  in Amazon and [the full book of Effective STL in China](http://www.uml.org.cn/c++/pdf/EffectiveSTL.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If you use C++0x:

```
ss.swap(stringstream());
```

[Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404879.aspx) (SP1) supports it.

If you don't use C++0x:

```
ss.seekp(0);
ss.seekg(0);
ss.str("");
ss.clear();
```

It won't clear the memory, but you could use your `stringstream` object as it would be empty before.