# reducing size of a stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stringstream

As an easy way to store several status logs etc. I have chosen a `std::stringstream`. In case of an error I can simply dump `.rdbuf()` into a file to be able to reproduce what my program has been doing before it crashed.

My problem now is, that this stringstream grows in size indefinitely. I have tried several things to ensure that I only keep the last 1MiB or so of the stream but have not been successful.

1. `.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(...)`
2. `.ignore(...)`
3. `getline(...)`
4. `ss.str() = ss.str().substr(...)`

Apparently the underlying buffer object always only increases in size - no matter whether some of the data has already been read or not.

Is there any way to reduce the size / hold it at some constant (preferably without regular deep copies)?
A circular buffer as an underlying buffer object would be perfect - is that possible? Esp. does that already exist?

---

**EDIT:** The solution basically has to behave like a stream. It is placed by the procompiler instead of std::err or a direct filestream (similar to the boost::log). It is therefore not strictly necessary, but very useful to use a stringstream. (Otherwise I would have to implement all the ostream stuff to be able to stream std::endl...)

Comment: Have you considered just using `std::ofstream` and flushing to a log file directly instead?

Comment: @AJG85 It gets too big. The program has to run 24/7 and would create several GiB of data per day. Anyway I don't really need all that log - I am only interested in the last few minutes (or seconds) before a crash.

Comment: There is a principle called "log rotation" that sounds applicable. You keep one or two "Old" and one "current" log-files. Every X units of time, you change the "current" to one of the older, and delete the oldest. In linux there are even tools to do this for you, as long as the log printing opens and closes the file reasonably often enough (if the file is kept open ALL the time, you just keep writing to the old file that has been deleted, because that how Unix style filesystems work).

Comment: Disk is cheap, memory is not. A common design for loggers is to use rolling files. When you surpass a certain size you close and rename an index of files dropping or archiving the oldest then open a new one. This would be configurable ideally. For a telecom server I implemented that also ran 24/7 I quite literally printed every entry and exit for every method of every thread and found 20 files at 25MB each was more than enough to trace any problem for the majority of sites.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You are a faster typist I see ;-)

Comment: @AJG85: I have years of practice!

Comment: @AJG85 I really only need a few MiB of log. And you really want to tell me that some MiB of ram are more expensive than Gigs of hdd? Apart from that I find that solution somewhat ugly. With my way I would have automated nice error-messages including a backtrace and my own log of what the program has been doing previous to every error. But lets ignore that error background for a moment. I would like to know a way to stop a stringstream from aggregating the already "removed" data without end irrespective of this particular usecase.

Comment: You can tailor the conditions to suit you. Mats suggestion of using intervals of time and tossing all but the most recent may be more to your liking. Most STL objects are designed to grow to capacity over their lifetime but you could use `oss.str(""); oss.clear();` to reset I believe.

Comment: If you want a circular buffered stringstream then I think you have to write your own streambuf.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370301/how-to-clear-the-buffer-of-a-streamstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my current STL implementation (VS2010 SP1), str("") releases all memory

```
std::stringstream ss;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<10000000; ++i)
{
    ss << "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLXCVBNM";
}

ss.str(""); // memory released here
```

[Reference:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) "Internally, the function calls the str member of its internal string buffer object."

I interpret that sentence to mean that if I assign an empty string, it'll copy-construct the underlying buffer to that.

Comment: I mistakingly called `ss.str() = ` assumingt `.str()` to return a reference.... I still think that even `.str("")` does not free the memory on my implementation (gcc 4.8), but the standard might have intended the memory to be freed (some implementations do so). So your answer is technically the correct one (I will accept it), even though I had to implement a rotation of several stringstreams in the end...

Comment: It is strange that the memory shouldn't get released then on gcc. A reset on the object would reset the read and write offsets, too. The only possibility would be if the underlying streambuf somehow holds on to the memory, because the external abstraction indeed reports 0 after the reset; see here:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d66fbc86e6c1c220 Of course calling pbase() would be more meaningful for that. I'm glad you got your problem solved though!

Comment: @Nikos Yes, but the OP's intent was to release the unused memory when recycling a stringstream object.